# New cube linked to the old object, how to make them separate?

Tags: objects, selection-tools

I am just starting out with blender and I don't know why the new cube that was added to the scene is tied to the old cube object.

Below image will explain

[image]

When I am selecting either of them, both get selected.
Please help me in deleting only the new cube. And please explain why it happened?

Comment: go in Edit mode, select the cube with L, delete it with X, go back to Object mode... you must have created your cube within the chair object, or you have accidentally joined it with ctrl J

Comment: @moonboots thank you this worked too, so new object should be added in Object mode only? And do you have any recommended guide that I should go through for learning modeling and animation?

Comment: you can use several meshes within the same object, but if you want to create a new object you generally don't create it within another one, you make sure you're in Object mode and create a new object. Grant Abbitt makes nice tutorials for beginners but you have many others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you added the little cube while you were in "Edit" mode, so it became part of the same mesh as the chair. You will need to go back into "Edit" mode, select all the faces of the little cube and delete them.

1. "tab" for edit mode
2. "alt"-a deselect all
3. "3" for face mode
4. select click a face on the little cube
5. "Ctrl"+l for all linked faces
6. "p" to separate to new item

Comment: thank you so much, you are a life saver, very well explained! 
So new object should be added in object mode, in edit mode they get linked?

PS I tried upvoting but requires 15 reputations..